# URL funnels at bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to build funnel through url's. But my request ended by error:  "Error: Cannot group by an aggregate."
So, that's request:

```
SELECT
COUNT(DISTINCT s1.clientId ) AS s1.User,
s1.page.pagePath
FROM (
SELECT
COUNT(DISTINCT clientId ) as User,
page.pagePath
FROM
[89437389479847487]
GROUP BY user,page.pagePath
HAVING
page.pagePath = 'URL 1'
AND page.pagePath != 'utm'
) AS s1
INNER JOIN (
SELECT
COUNT(DISTINCT clientId ) AS User,
page.pagePath
FROM
[89437389479847487]
GROUP BY user,page.pagePath
HAVING
page.pagePath = 'URL 2'
AND page.pagePath != 'utm') AS s2
ON 
s1.User=s2.User
GROUP BY s1.user,s1.page.pagePath
```

Where can be a mistake? Thanks.

Update: I fixed request, but still have error:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(DISTINCT s1.clientId ) Auser ,
  s1.page.pagePath
FROM (
  SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT clientId ) AS user ,
    page.pagePath
  FROM
    [limetest.limetableempty]
  WHERE
    page.pagePath CONTAINS '/internet/calc2/'
    AND page.pagePath != 'utm_'
  GROUP BY page.pagePath
) s1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT clientId ) AS user,
    page.pagePath
  FROM
    [limetest.limetableempty]
  WHERE
    page.pagePath CONTAINS '/help/'
    AND page.pagePath != 'utm_' AND page.pagePath != 'utm_' 
  GROUP BY 
page.pagePath) s2
ON
s1.clientId=s2.clientId
    GROUP BY s1.page.pagePath
```

Error: "Field 'clientId' not found".
I'm trying to build transition funnel between two urls ('/internet/calc2/' and '/help/').

Comment: I guess the issue in this: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT clientId ) AS **User** ...
GROUP BY **user** ...  What do you want to do? You can't group by aggregate function. Not in the same query.

Comment: Thanks! I updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on avilable info in your question, I would recommend to try below:

```
SELECT 
  s1.page,
  COUNT(s1.clientId ) AS usersAtFunnelStart,
  COUNT(s2.clientId ) AS usersAtFunnelEnd
FROM (
  SELECT
    page.pagePath AS page,
    clientId
  FROM
    [limetest.limetableempty]
  WHERE
    page.pagePath CONTAINS '/internet/calc2/'
    AND page.pagePath != 'utm_'
  GROUP BY 1, 2
) s1
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT 
    clientId
  FROM
    [limetest.limetableempty]
  WHERE
    page.pagePath CONTAINS '/help/'
    AND page.pagePath != 'utm_' 
  GROUP BY 1
) s2
ON s1.clientId = s2.clientId
GROUP BY s1.page
```